# Report with relations

Tags: qgis, print-composer, atlas, relation

I collected field data containing general information about signpost sites (location, altitude, image) and specific information of the particular signs mounted to the singpost (image, direction). One site may contain multiple boards.

I built a Geopackage with a georeferenced point table containing the signpost signs and created a one to many relation to another table in the GPK containing the information of the signs.

Now, I try to represent one signpost site incl. the related signs via print composer report. One page should be one site. The defining layer for the report is the layer with the signposts.

I don't know how to access resp. represent the relation and need help therefore. 
I managed to show the attribute table of the relation, which does not help the display the image.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access attributes from another layer in your atlas-driven map layout, you can use the **`aggregate()` function**, with the filter being the join condition (i.e. the ID number in your atlas layer matches the ID number in the other layer). Please read through the other answers on this site and the [official documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/expression.html#aggregates-functions) to learn more.

The returned attribute value can be used in a text label or in a filepath to show an image, etc.

However, since you have a one-to-many relationship, you need to set up your report to have one image frame for the each relationship (so if one point has max 5 images you will need 5 image frames)

Then you need to use **[array functions](https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/expression.html#array-functions)** to get an array of matches, then extract the first match in the first frame, the second match in the second frame, etc...

---

Let's say your images are in a subfolder of your project folder, called `Image_Folder`, and your photos field is called `image` and contains just the filename of the image with the extension.

## First image frame

Set up your first image frame and under Item Properties next to Image Source, click the little ε sign next to it as below.

[image]

This will bring up the expression editor. You would need to adapt an expression like the one below **for the first frame**

```
@project_folder||'\\Image_Folder\\   
  array_get(
    aggregate('other_layer',
              'array_agg',
              "image",
              "other_layer_id"=
                attribute(@parent,
               'atlas_layer_id'))
    ,0)
```

This will return the first matching `image` value (first array element = `0`) from the **array** of matching `image` values.

## Second image frame

Then in your second frame, repeat the above, but when entering the expression you need to change the `0` to `1` as you now want the *second* matching image (=second array element = `1`).

## How to handle NULL matches

What happens if you don't have a second image for this feature, though? You will get a `NULL` value and a giant ugly X where the image should be. To avoid that, we want the expression to default to a blank image if a `NULL` is returned, by using `coalesce()` like so:

```
coalesce(
  @project_folder||'\\Image_Folder\\
    array_get(
      aggregate('other_layer',
                'array_agg',
                "image",
                "other_layer_id"=
                  attribute(@parent,
                 'atlas_layer_id'))
      ,1),
  'C:\\Users\\Template\\Pictures\\
   empty.jpg')
```

## Result example

Here is an example with trees. The first feature has two matching images from the other layer, so it's all good...

[image]

But the second feature only has one matching image - so in the second frame it defaults to a small 10x10 px white square which you can't see.

[image]